# Illegal characters in filenames of a .jar file which android studio is not accepting

Tags: android, android-studio, character-encoding, stanford-nlp, illegal-characters

I wanted to use StanfordCoreNLP  library in my android app . So i have imported the .jar files using the following dependencies in my gradle.build file . 
 [These are my gradle dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysv5Z.png)

The Files are imported properly but many of the files in the .jar file have ':' character in their names which the android studio wont accept .You can see the names here .
[Filenames with invalid characters in .jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwXa1.png)

So i got an error as below when i tried to make the project .
 [com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 43: edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/tokensregex/org:founded_by.rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIIEH.png)

And the [homepage of stanfordCoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html) says that the lib works fine with utf-8 encoding but it is'nt .[Encoding snippet from homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YrrI.png)

So does anyone have an idea how to make android studio accept the ':' character .
Thanks in  advance for any help .

Comment: I'm going to try to fix this file issue today by removing the ":" from the file names

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the most recent releases.  This is fixed in the code on the GitHub site, and we will probably do a release fairly soon to include this fix:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP

You can build a version of the latest code...follow the instructions from GitHub.