# How to build an android app using Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1?

Tags: android, stanford-nlp

I want to build an app with NLP processing to be done on the device itself. For this I want to use StanfordCoreNLP. I want to know how to import the library in the android app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of importing all the dependencies to an Android project, you should set up a dedicated Stanford CoreNLP server and then make your Android application interact with the server using REST API.

Refer this documentation of [Stanford CoreNLP dedicated server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html)

To parse a sentence and get JSON output:

```
wget --post-data 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' 'localhost:9000/?properties={"annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos", "outputFormat": "json"}
```

or you can use HTTP Library to send data to the server also.

Comment: But its the requirement of the project to import the library and to the processing on device without using the server client approach

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that but I need only some of the models of the library.

Comment: My friend is facing this issue. Can you provide some help on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055961/illegal-characters-in-filenames-of-a-jar-file-which-android-studio-is-not-accep